# What is the meaning of using median instead of mean to calculate sample variance?

Tags: variance, mean, median

I am reading the source code of MAGeCK 0.5.9.5 which is a popular software for analyzing CRISPR knockout screen data. In its mageckMathFunc.py, it calculates "mean" and "variance" as follows:

```
def mmedian(lst):
  sortedLst = sorted(lst)
  lstLen = len(lst)
  if lstLen==0:
    return 0.0
  index = (lstLen - 1) // 2

  if (lstLen % 2):
    return sortedLst[index]
  else:
    return (sortedLst[index] + sortedLst[index + 1])/2.0

def getMeans(matt):
  meanvalue=[mmedian(v) for v in matt]
  return meanvalue

def getVars(matt):
  matt=list(matt)
  meanvalue=getMeans(matt)
  varvalue=[ sum([ (kj-meanvalue[i])*(kj-meanvalue[i])  for kj in matt[i]  ]  )/max(float(len(matt[i]))-1,1.0)    for i in range(len(meanvalue))]
  return varvalue
```

Then it uses their return values to use as sample mean and sample variance
extensively throughout the code. Apparently, they are not the conventional
mean and variance based on simple arithmetic mean. Is there a name for this
type of "sample mean" and "sample variance" based on median? Under what
circumstances should we use them instead of the conventional ones?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This looks weird. If the median is used as a location parameter, it is more common to use the inter quartile range (IQR) as a measure for dispersion.

Comment: It is indeed weird. I try to write R code to reproduce the MAGeCK numbers. I must use this definition of variance to get the numbers right.

Comment: This would work with large datasets having no outliers.  It makes no statistical sense, though, because (a) one uses the median to obtain a location estimate that is resistant to outlying values but (b) using the squared deviations from *anything* is even *more* sensitive to outliers than the arithmetic mean that was avoided in the first place! One way to understand this calculation is that it returns the sum of the (usual) variance and the squared difference between the mean and median.  As such, it estimates a somewhat complicated quantity describing both *spread* and *skewness.*

Answer (score 2):

***Comment:*** I am not sure of the formula for your variance estimate or the purpose in using something other than
the usual sample variance $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$, where $\bar X$ is the sample mean.

Perhaps [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177052/using-the-median-for-calculating-variance?rq=1) linked in the margin is relevant.

Also, perhaps consider the function `mad` for [Median Absolute Deviation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/mad) in R. Roughly, it is the median of the absolute deviations from the sample median.

MAD has been proposed as a robust measure of variability.

For a normal sample, when `mad` is multiplied by $1.4826.$ (the default in R), its expected value is the normal standard deviation $\sigma.$

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(10000, 100, 15)
mad(x)
[1] 14.79603  # aprx 15
sd(x)
[1] 14.81294
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the code, it uses the median and the "variance" relative to median to find outliers by setting a cutoff of median+4*sqrt("variance" relative to median). It just uses them as if they are the conventional sample mean and sample variance. In order to reproduce the numbers in the output of MAGeCK, I have to use this definition of variance. I am aware of MAD but not this. I am not sure about the rationale behind it, so I try to see if anyone here knows.