# What is the maximum likelihood/GLM version of least absolute deviations for robust linear regression?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, robust, least-absolute-deviations

Robust linear regression from minimising the absolute deviationresults in a regression line of *medians* conditional on covariates, instead of *means* using the standard least squares methodology: [Is minimizing squared error equivalent to minimizing absolute error? Why squared error is more popular than the latter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147001/is-minimizing-squared-error-equivalent-to-minimizing-absolute-error-why-squared/147044#147044)

It is useful and robust in the sense that it minimises the effect of outliers in the response variable on the fitted line. What is its analogue in the generalised linear model/maximum likelihood setting?

Comment: I read somewhere else that minimising the absolute deviation in linear regression is equivalent to assuming an error term that is Laplace distributed. This suggests that the likelihood function (for the robust Gaussian GLM) is obtained by assuming the response distribution is Laplace.

Comment: One reason squared error is more popular is that the objective function is quadratic and minimization, in the purely linear case, is very easy - and in the GLM case can be done easily via a Newton-like iterative procedure or any of many others.  However, LAD regression requires setting up a linear program or something equivalent thereto and is slower.

Comment: I understand that. However, I cannot find any references to LAD-like regression for GLMs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no GLM (no natural exponential family model) that corresponds to L1 (Least absolute value) regression.*

Note that if you're doing MLE then a density of form $\frac{c}{\phi}\exp(-g(\frac{y-\mathbf{x}\beta}{\phi}))$ with have log-likelihood $-n\log(\phi)-\sum_i  g(\frac{y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\beta}{\phi})$.

Now maximizing likelihood with respect to the parameters in $\beta$ would correspond to minimizing $\sum_i  g(\frac{y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\beta}{\phi})$.

So if you're trying to minimize $\frac{1}{\phi}\sum_i  |y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\beta|=\sum_i  |\frac{y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\beta}{\phi}| $... the form of $g$ and hence of the density of the errors that this will be ML for should be immediately obvious -- it's the [Laplace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).

> It is useful and robust in the sense that it minimises the effect of outliers in the response variable on the fitted line

It provides no protection at all against *influential*  observations, and so it's not at all robust to influential outliers, as illustrated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46229/fast-linear-regression-robust-to-outliers/51822#51822).

---

I also don't think it's *quite* correct to say it minimizes the effect; (ignoring the above point about influential observations -- e.g. if we're just looking at location rather than regression) it bounds the effect very nicely but if you learn about influence functions and M-estimators you'll see that there are estimators with influence functions that redescend (which L1 estimators don't), and so there's estimators of location where outliers have even less effect than they  do on the median.

---

* Leaving aside the scale$^\dagger$ for simplicity, you just can't write $\sum_i  |y_i-\mathbf{x}_i\beta|$ in the form $\sum_i -\eta(\beta)\cdot T(y_i) +A(\beta)-B(y_i)$ - the absolute value function doesn't break up like that.

$\dagger$ Actually if we only had the scale to estimate, that *would* be exponential family.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no GLM equivalent at all of robust regression as there is no distribution from the exponential family that can be used as the response distribution. For the MLE part, where does the density you have written come from, is this some form of the density of a distribution from the exponential family? Then further on, when you say that the density of errors is the Laplace, does this mean that for all regression types (Poisson, logistic etc) you assume that the response is Laplace distributed?

Comment: You should not make the mistake of thinking that "robust regression" means L1 regression; remove that habit from your mind. Robust regression includes many things; L1 regression is considered by some people to be robust, but my answer makes it clear why many other people *don't* consider it robust (it can be arbitrarily affected by a single observation as my linked example clearly demonstrates! Its breakdown point is $1/n$ -- in regression terms it's really no more robust to sufficiently influential gross errors than OLS). Even if you do consider it robust it's just one of many possibilities.

Comment: As a result, it takes rather more than what I discuss above to make the claim "there is no GLM equivalent at all of robust regression" because we haven't *looked* at all of robust regression.

Comment: The density form that I wrote is simply a way of converting loss functions that you minimize (i.e. the $\sum_i g_i$) to a corresponding density that minimizing $\sum g$ would also be ML for (minimizing $\sum g$ maximizes $\sum -g$, which is maximizing $exp(\sum -g_i)=\prod_i exp(-g_i)$ which is now (up to scaling factors) in the form of a likelihood; so a density of that $exp(-g(z))$ form is one that has a MLE that corresponds to using $\sum_i g(z_i)$ as a loss function. In general such functions are not in the exponential family, they're more general. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... however, the exponential family is of the form $f_{X}(x\mid \theta )=\exp \left(\eta (\theta )\cdot T(x)-A(\theta )+B(x)\right)$, so they fall into that very, very general framework (we can see that there's a simple "loss function" for any member of the exponential family we can immediately write down, $\sum_i -\eta(\theta)\cdot T(y_i) +A(\theta)-B(y_i))$  (note that the predictors appear in $\eta$, and we can drop the term in $B$ without affecting the fit). Your last question makes no sense to me. You were asking which density would have L1 regression as ML. It's the Laplace. ...ctd

Comment: ctd... but if you use L1 on something else it doesn't mean you *assume* that thing is Laplace; there's no law forcing you to use ML. If you say "I'm using L1" you're also saying "irrespective of what the distribution is, I'm using this estimator" -- it won't be ML but so what? -- you didn't pick L1 to get an ML estimate. If you have a good idea what the density is like, you should start with that (and possibly robustify it in case you're not quite correct) rather than with L1 -- otherwise if your distribution is clearly far from Laplace you may well be estimating very inefficiently

Comment: My confusion with "*assume* that thing is Laplace" comes from the wikipedia statement: " The least absolute deviations estimate also arises as the maximum likelihood estimate if the errors have a Laplace distribution." So, taking this further, in linear regression, the response is the fitted mean + error,  $y = \mu + \epsilon$. Assuming a normal distribution for the error term, $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma)$ implies $y \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$. Thus, doesn't $\epsilon \sim \operatorname{Laplace}(0, b)$ imply $y \sim \operatorname{Laplace}(\mu, b)$? (Aside that the Laplace may not be a good fit.)

Comment: The quote is true. But as I have explained just because you're using a loss function that would correspond to ML for some distribution doesn't necessarily imply you have assumed that distribution to be the case. [If it *is* the case, then that's great for you, since you are also doing ML, and that usually means you have a bunch of nice properties including efficient estimators.]

Comment: Ok thanks, I think the ideas are starting to solidify in my mind. Perhaps a better way of phrasing my question would be: Suppose $N(\mu, \sigma) \rightarrow \operatorname{Laplace}(\mu, b)$, where $\rightarrow$ denotes that the Laplacian max likelihood estimator is *reasonable* to model the data generative process with outliers. Then, what are the equivalents for $\operatorname{Bern}(p) \rightarrow ?$ or $\operatorname{Pois}(\mu) \rightarrow ?$. Or is a general 'rule of thumb' distribution not feasible since the source of the outlier data points should  be modelled on a case by case basis?

Comment: equivalent in what sense? When you change the distribution you also change relationships between distributions (for example, the normal is continuous on the real line while the Poisson is only on the positive integers -- one cannot consider simply "adding noise" or take a mixture over a variance parameter, for example -- you must make it clear what kind of equivalence you're talking about (one could quite reasonably argue that the equivalent is to use L1 each time). You're essentially asking an entirely new question but your question is too vague for a new post (it would close as unclear).

Comment: Equivalent in the sense of the following modelling context: I have a response variable which I assume to be normally distributed but *sometimes* I expect there to be outliers in the response (either too high or too low). Then, from wiki: "The simplest methods of estimating parameters in a regression model that are less sensitive to outliers than the least squares estimates, is to use least absolute deviations." Applying this *simplest method* (whether right or wrong), means I replace the normal distribution with the Laplace if I am thinking of it as a ML problem. ...ctd...

Comment: ...ctd... What if now the response is binary 0/1's, but I expect that sometimes I observe more 0's or 1's than expected (my outliers). Is there a similar 'simplest method' of fitting the regression parameters? But yes, I think I agree with you that this question may be too vague as it depends on the (assumed) generation process of the outliers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57722/discussion-between-alex-and-glen-b).