# Linear regression minimising MAD in sklearn

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, scikit-learn

The [standard sklearn linear regression class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) finds an approximated linear relationship between variate and covariates that minimises the mean squared error (MSE). Specifically, let $N$ be the number of observations and let us ignore the intercept for simplicity. Let $y_j$ be the variate value of the $j$-th observation and $x_{1,j}, \dots, x_{n,j}$ be the values of the $n$ covariates of the $j$-th observation. The linear relationship is of the form
$$ y = \beta_1 x_1 + \dots \beta_n x_n;$$
where the coefficients $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n$ are given by
$$\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n = \underset{\tilde\beta_1, \dots, \tilde\beta_n}{\mathrm{argmin}} \left( \sum_{j = 1}^N \left( y_j - \tilde\beta_1x_{1, j} - \dots -\tilde\beta_nx_{n, j}\right)^2 \right).$$

I now wish to find the coefficients that minimise the mean absolute deviation (MAD) instead of the mean squared error. Namely, I want the coefficients given by
$$\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n = \underset{\tilde\beta_1, \dots, \tilde\beta_n}{\mathrm{argmin}} \left( \sum_{j = 1}^N \left| y_j - \tilde\beta_1x_{1, j} - \dots -\tilde\beta_nx_{n, j}\right| \right).$$

I understand that, in sharp contrast to the MSE case, the lack of differentiability of the absolute value function at $0$ implies there is no analytic solution for the MAD case. But the latter is still a convex optimisation problem, and, according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/147006/220246) answer, it can be easily solved by means of linear programming.

Is it possible to implement this linear regression in sklearn? What about using other statistics toolkits?

Comment: I just nominated this for reopening. Yes, the question is about how to perform a task in sklearn or Python in general. But *it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer*, which is [explicitly on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @StephanKolassa I agree with you - the question should be reopened..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The expected MAD is minimized by the median of the distribution ([Hanley, 2001, *The American Statistician*](https://doi.org/10.1198/000313001750358482); see also [Why does minimizing the MAE lead to forecasting the median and not the mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/355538/1352)). Therefore, you are looking for a model that will yield the *conditional median*, instead of the *conditional mean*.

This is a special case of [quantile-regression](/questions/tagged/quantile-regression), specifically for the 50% quantile. [Roger Koenker is the main guru for quantile regression](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Roger+koenker+%22quantile+regression%22); see in particular [his book *Quantile Regression*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521845734).

There are ways to do quantile regression in Python. [This tutorial may be helpful.](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/quantile-regression-in-python) If you are open to using R, you can use the [`quantreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=quantreg) package.

Comment: In python it is available vis statsmodels https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression.QuantReg.html

Comment: Thanks! It is an easy way to look at the problem indeed...

Comment: For an update, currently sklearn has quantile regression as well http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.QuantileRegressor.html